# I insist on them getting X I insist on getting sth for them

Tags: grammar, verbs

What is it that sometimes I can put a noun instead of an ING verb:

> I insist on getting a present for them.
>
> I insist on **them** getting a present.

In the latter, is the meaning the same? I cannot think of another example (with another verb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is not the same. 'Getting' can mean both buying a present ready to give, and receiving a present as a gift. The two sentences change who is doing the action, which person is "getting the present" and what kind of 'getting' is being described.

*"I insist on getting a present for them"* means: I will act, I will get a present. Then I will give the present to them.

e.g. "We are going to a party. The invitation said that presents are optional, but I insist on getting a present for them".

*I insist on them getting a present"* means: I will do nothing. I demand that they receive a present. I will not give the present, I do not specify who will give the present, it might be clear from the context.

e.g. "You said that everyone who entered the competiton would get a present. This person entered, and you do not want to give them a present? I insist on them getting a present".

*"I insist on them getting a present"* also means: I will do nothing. I demand someone else buys a present ready to give to someone unspecified.

e.g. "Both families are going and we agreed to bring a present each, now they want to join up and share our present. I insist on them getting a present as well."

Edit: I re-read it, and saw another interpretation. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What is it that sometimes I can put a noun instead of an ING verb

You are not putting anything instead of anything, you are just changing the order of some words in your sentence — and yes, you change the meaning of the sentence.

To illustrate, let's rewrite your first sentence a little bit:

> I insist on [*someone*] getting a present for them.

Is equivalent to:

> I insist on [*someone*] getting them a present.

*Get* is used as a ditransitive verb, which means it takes a direct object, *as well* as an indirect object. In your sentence, you have left out the *subject* of *getting*, but it is still there, implied. *Them* is the *indirect object* (and _a present is the *direct object*.

Now, let's see what happens when you write your second sentence:

> I insist on *them* getting [*someone*] a present.

You have not switched *them* and *getting*, you have switched *them* and *someone*!
In other words, you have switched the (indirect) object of the sentence with the subject, and that changes the meaning considerably!

In English, the position of the subject and the (direct or indirect) object in a sentence is not random; we actually infer from the position the role in the sentence:

> Alice hits Bob.

This would normally be understood to mean that Bob receives the beating. Changing the positions of Alice and Bob around the verb makes Bob the aggressor:

> Bob hits Alice.

In the same way, you swapped the (implied) subject with the (indirect) object, meaning that you changed the meaning accordingly:

> I insist on *them* getting [*someone*] a present. -> ***they** buy the present, **someone** receives it.*
>   I insist on [*someone*] getting *them* a present. -> ***someone** buys the present, **they** receive it.*